# Laravel 4 querying relational relation

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I've created 4 database tables:

Tool
 
ID | NAME | TOOLTYPE_ID

Tooltype
 
ID | NAME

Toolcategory
 
ID | NAME

Tool_Toolcategory
 
TOOL_ID | TOOLCATEGORY_ID

The models are as following:

```
class Tool extends Eloquent  {

 public function toolCategories()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('ToolCategory', 'tool_toolcategory', 'tool_id', 'toolcategory_id');
 }

 public function tooltype()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('ToolType');
 }   
}

class ToolType extends Eloquent {

 public function tools()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Tool', 'tooltype_id');
 }
}

class ToolCategory extends Eloquent {
 public function tools()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tool', 'tool_toolcategory', 'tool_id', 'toolcategory_id');
 }   
}
```

Ok, my problem is getting toolcategories based on created tools with a specific tooltype.
 
*Example* I want all the categories related to the tools that has the type "Software".
 I am kinda lost, i have looked at trying to use scope in my toolcategory model, doing something like this:

```
public function scopeHasType($query, $type)
{
  return $query->whereHas('tools.tooltype', function($q) use ($type) 
  {
    $q->where('name', '=', $type);
  })->exists();
}
```

which didn't really work :) then i tried this

```
$categories = ToolCategory::whereHas('tools.tooltype', function($query)
{
  $query->where('tooltype_id', '=', 'Software');                
})->get();
```

again no luck. So i was hoping that this makes sense to someone, and they could push me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent naming convention says:

1. ModelNames are `StudlyCased` & singular
2. modelMethods are `camelCased` (relation dynamic properties need this)
3. table_names are `snake_cased` & plural
4. table_columns are `snake_cased`
5. pivot_table is `model1_model2` snake_cased singular (in alphabetical order)

That being said, Eloquent for a model `ToolCategory` looks for the table `tool_categories`.

So you need to specify table names whenever are not convention compliant (singular, not snake cased and so on):

```
// for example Tool model
protected $table = 'tool';
```

Also you need foreign keys to be passed to the relationship definition in order to let Eloquent know what to look for. However that you already did:

```
// ToolType model
public function tools()
{
    // here Eloquent would look for tool_type_id (based on related model)
    return $this->hasMany('Tool', 'tooltype_id');
}

// Tool model
public function tooltype()
{
    // here Eloquent looks for tooltype_id by default (based on relation name)
    return $this->belongsTo('ToolType');
}
```

---

Now, your relations are OK with 1 exception (keys wrong order):

```
class ToolCategory extends Eloquent {
 public function tools()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tool', 'tool_toolcategory', 'toolcategory_id', 'tool_id');
 }
```

---

Finally, `whereHas` doesn't work on nested relation (yet, check this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4954), so at the moment you need this:

```
// ToolCategory model
public function scopeHasType($query, $type) 
{
  return $query->whereHas('tools', function ($q) use ($type) {
    $q->whereHas('tooltype', function($q) use ($type) {
      // use table prefix, since this is going to be join
      $q->where('tooltype.name', '=', $type);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Great the nested scope works! Also the wrong key order, well spotted :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome little cheat sheet for Eloquent naming convention!!